# execute sql file containing oracle block

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Need help. I am a new beginner in Visual studio C#. 
I am creating an WINDOWS FORM APPLICATION with just a button and text box. What basically i want to do is to run a sql file containing a oracle block in it and want the output(dbms_output) generated from the block to shown in the text box.

Till now I accomplished to call sqlplus and execute the file and also retrieve the output via a message box.
But when I try to do the same with text box , i get below run time error.

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
>         Message=Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
>         Source=System.Windows.Forms
>         StackTrace:
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_WindowText(String value)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.set_WindowText(String value)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Text(String value)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.set_Text(String value)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.set_Text(String value)
>              at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.myProcess_OutputDataReceived(Object
>   sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\sj0087652.TECHMAHINDRA\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 22
>              at System.Diagnostics.Process.OutputReadNotifyUser(String data)
>              at System.Diagnostics.AsyncStreamReader.FlushMessageQueue()
>              at System.Diagnostics.AsyncStreamReader.GetLinesFromStringBuilder()
>              at System.Diagnostics.AsyncStreamReader.ReadBuffer(IAsyncResult ar)
>              at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg)
>              at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, IMessageSink replySink)
>              at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.DoAsyncCall()
>              at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.ThreadPoolCallBack(Object
>   o)
>              at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object
>   state)
>              at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)
>              at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>              at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
>              at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
>         InnerException:

Now my questions are as following:

1. How can i get the output in text box.
2. Is there any better way of handling exceptions.
3. And is there any better way to execute sql file containing oracle block via C#.

Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void myProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Data);
        textBox1.Text += e.Data;
    }

    void myProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exit");

    }

    void myProcess_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error", e.Data);
    } 
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "sqlplus.exe";
        myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "";
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-s hr/hr@XE";
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        myProcess.OutputDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(myProcess_OutputDataReceived);
        myProcess.ErrorDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(myProcess_ErrorDataReceived);
        myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
        myProcess.Start();
        myProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
        myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        myProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("@C:\\Users\\sj0087652\\Documents\\trial_script.sql");

        myProcess.Close(); 
    }
           public System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess { get; set; }
}

}
)
```

Comment: The trouble is that you are trying to set the text from another thread, if you are on .Net 4.5 `async`/`await` will solve your problem. Otherwise you are best off setting a string in your class to the output and using a Timer to poll for a result. Or you can use `BeginInvoke` to run some code on the GUI thread (this is probably your best option): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089.aspx

Comment: I am using visual express c# 2010.
It would help me , if you edit my code and provide the correct code as i am a new programmer.
Many thanks for ur reply...

Comment: I've amended it to contain everything obviously needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably your best option:

```
delegate void AddContentDelegate(string Text);
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    AddContentDelegate AddContent;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AddContent = new AddContentDelegate(AddContentFunction);
    }

    void AddContentFunction(string Text)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Text);
        textBox1.Text += Text + "\r\n";
    }


    void myProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        BeginInvoke(AddContent, e.Data);
    }

    void myProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exit");

    }

    void myProcess_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error", e.Data);
    } 
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "sqlplus.exe";
        myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "";
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-s hr/hr@XE";
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        myProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(myProcess_OutputDataReceived);
        myProcess.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(myProcess_ErrorDataReceived);
        myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
        myProcess.Start();
        myProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
        myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        myProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("@C:\\Users\\sj0087652\\Documents\\trial_script.sql");

        myProcess.Close(); 
    }
    public System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess;
}
```

`BeginInvoke` will call the function (or Delegate in this case) on the GUI thread. The error you are getting is because it is trying to edit the textbox across threads.

You might want to change it to `Invoke` to prevent being spammed with popup boxes. The only difference is `Invoke` will wait until the function has finished before continuing.

Comment: many thanks... It works :). 
the output which come to my text box is a without new line character.

block complete PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. block complete PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Can you please suggest . I want the output like below.

   block complete (new line)

   PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.(new line)

   block complete (new line)

   PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Comment: @user3870268 You just need to add a new line when you print it (I've edited the post). If I helped, please mark me as answer!

Comment: I am printing the new line, but its not being printed in the text box..
Also let me know how to mark you as answerer :)

Comment: Is the box marked as multiline? When you select it there should be a checkbox on the top right hand corner of the box you can tick?

Comment: Yes it is selected. I have also tried rich text box. But same result.:(

Comment: I have done by  textBox1.Text += Text+ Environment.NewLine;

many thanks for your help :)